# Dojo - ScrollingTabControllerMenuButton freezes TabContainer in Firefox

Tags: dojo, tabcontainer, dijit.layout

I recently by accident found an issue I have with a web application I have made entirely with dojo.

I have a TabContainer and a toolbar with buttons and each button adds a Tab in the TabContainer.
Each of these new Tabs has as children, created programmatically, one or more of the following `BorderContainers, ContePanes, Editors, FilteringSelects, Uploader and Buttons`. I should point out that I do not have parseonLoad: true byt false and I call manually the parsers.parse when required. I should point out that in the ContentPanes in the content attribute I put also declarative filteringSelects and ValidationTexts and Uploader I hope that is not a problem.

Everything is working great in all browsers even in IE9 besides one thing in Firefox 12.
When I create many new tabs and the ScrollingTabController gets created (The left/right and dropdown arrows of the tabstrip) when I use the ScrollingTabControllerMenuButton (the down arrow at the far right) the TabContainer behaves wrongly and eventually freezes. Firebug shows weird errors when I select different tabs via this menu of the tab strip. Errors of the buttons that I have in these tabs, weird errors mentioning `StackController` or `ScrollingTabController`

[ e.g.

button is undefined

```
if(this._selectedTab === button.domNode){  StackController.js (line 222) ]
```

different each time...

This weird behavior only happens in Firefox. IE9 and Chrome do not have any issue at all!

Could anyone have an idea on what might be the problem? Is it a known bug? Is it a problem that I have many widgets in each Tab ?

Comment: From how you explain this, it definately sounds like a browser-specific bug. Maybe you can find an answer here : http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/search?q=scrollingtabcontroller&noquickjump=1&ticket=on&milestone=on&changeset=on&wiki=on or place a new ticket with the above information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is indeed a browser specific bug and as I was told it should be fixed in the following releases

I first reported it to the dojo community and from there they reported it to the Firefox team

http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/15496